# "Unknown response prefix: 'H'" when connecting to redis in laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, php-7, laradock, predis

I have tried "telnet 12.123.123.123 80" and using redis-commander. Everthing works perfectly fine but when run the code, it shows "Unknown response prefix: 'H'". Here's my code:

```
$redisResultData = \RedisServer::connection('td_slave')->PING();
```

/config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
   'RedisServer' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class
]
```

/config/database.php:

```
'td_slave' => [
            'host' => '12.123.123.123',
            'password' => null,
            'port' => 80,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
```

Error msg:

```
"Unknown response prefix: 'H'. [tcp://12.123.123.123:80], file:/var/www/melon_back_member/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php, line:167"
```

When I try this:

```
dd(config('database.redis.td_slave'),\RedisServer::connection('td_slave'));
```

It shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using `HHVM` as your PHP compiler inside your `laradock` instance, change it to `PHP-FPM`, it should work fine.